# Why was my question about a python feature closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Why was [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304227/serving-logs-via-http) closed? What would be the correct site to post it at? I tried to write a solution in Python and it didn't work out, and as Python is a programming language I really don't know why it was marked as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was closed because it is not related to a programming problem.  It's a system administration problem, really.  I would not vote to close it if it were on Serverfault.

Comment: thank you squillman. I will post it there, but i hope it's not gonna be considered as cross-posting.

Comment: You should be fine.  You could flag the question on SO for migration to SF, a diamond mod can still forcefully migrate it.  If not, put a comment on it saying it was originally posted on SO and that should stave off the cross-posting police.

Comment: The boundary between SE and SF can be painful, especially as SF is specifically for *professional* system administrators. So, if you have a non-professional system administration issue closely related to your programming task, you're out of luck: there is nowhere to ask.

Comment: In that case I would post it on Superuser.